# How to set fotorama thumbnail as vertical

Tags: magento2, fotorama

I am using magento 2 porto theme. In product details page i need to set the thumbnail of fotorama slider to left as vertical. Is it possible?? Please help

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Go to the the file **app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/etc/view.xml**

We can see a variable **navdir**.

This variable has ability to change the thumbnails alignment in Fotorama.

By default it is set as:

`<var name="navdir"> horizontal</var>`

Change the code like this:

`<var name="navdir"> vertical</var>`

to make the thumbnails as vertical.

Comment: Amazing response. I was actually in big trouble which is solved. Thank u

Comment: Is there any need to compile theme after doing this changes?

Comment: After doing this.. thumbnail navigation that is thumbnail arrows not working. I checked in html there is disabled class is applied for this both top and bottom arrows. Any solution?

Comment: Bootstrap can break Fotorama, may need to add ".gallery-placeholder{width: 100%;}" to your css

Comment: If that file doesn't exist, then it needs to be created, and have the correct XML tags in. It should look like this:
`<?xml version="1.0" ?> <view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd"> <vars module="Magento_Catalog"> <var name="gallery"> <var name="navdir">vertical</var> </var> </vars> </view>`